# Error while setting ApplicationContext in Spring unit test

Tags: java, spring, junit, java-ee-7

I have a file :

```
properties/spring/test.xml
```

I can access this file in :

```
InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("properties/spring/test.xml");
    String theString = IOUtils.toString(in);
```

but I cannot whith this invocation in the same method :

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("properties/spring/test.xml");
```

Here is th error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.identityToString(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:58)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.bnppa.ws.pub.commons.HubPartnerSSOConsumer.v1.HubPartnerSSOConsumerSOAPImplTest.setUp(HubPartnerSSOConsumerSOAPImplTest.java:33)
```

I am using Spring 3.2.13.RELEASE
and JUNIT 4.11.

Comment: Which version of Spring-core are you using?

Comment: Without knowing the content of file `properties/spring/test.xml`, it is hard to say, but the error let think that the file in not a valid application context and it has syntax errors.

Comment: Judging from the stacktrace you are mixing jars of different versions of Spring. Check your classpath and dependencies.

Comment: You are right, I have Spring 1.2.8 forgotten in the classpath. @Serge : test.xml is a basic empty file

Comment: If the cleaning of classpath is not enough, try to put an empty but syntactically correct application context xml file coherent with the version of spring that you use.